# form with no instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view, controller

sorry if my english is bad,

I have this rails app and I want to make a form in the ***header partial*** for another controller where users just put their email and submit it. The problem for me is that I don't have any instance variable and I don't know how to point to the create action to the controller of the form, because I'm in one layout's view. I kind of want to be remote too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question I think you're looking for something like this.

```
<% form_for :action, :url=>{:controller=> 'controller',:action=> 'action'} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked but its :controller insted of :action right after the form_for.